# Does jquery 3.3.1 support jquery-validation 1.17.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have started up a new project and it requires me to use all the latest release of the jquery. so i have used jquery3.3.1 but i am not able to find whether this version is compatible with the jquery-validation 1.17.0

Comment: Yes, it's fine https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqshxgd/

Answer (score 4):

According to the jQuery Validation docs, it seems to be fine:

https://jqueryvalidation.org

> Dependencies
>   Required
>   jQuery, tested with 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.1, 1.11.1,
>   3.1.1

At least with 3.1.1 anyway... Give it a try and you'll soon run into any issues if there are any.

Comment: is that  the only way to find whether it is compatible or not? i was excepting something like a documentation to support the claim. is there any documentation? if yes could u please guide me how to look at it.. thanks

Comment: @LijinDurairaj,are you kidding?   The entire point of the answer is that he got the information from the documentation.   You can just go see for yourself.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj I'm not sure what you're expecting. As I stated in my answer, the jQuery Validation home page states that it has been tested with jQuery 3.1.1. As the latest version (3.3.1) is only a minor version update, you can assume that they are still fully compatible, given that minor version updates do not change the API at all. All you have to do is give it a try and you should be able to soon see if it is working like you expect it to.

Comment: The OP does not even realize that you already gave him exactly what he's complaining about.  It's congruent with what's going on in the original question... laziness.